# Is there any shortcut to insert a math equation for Powerpoint 2016 Mac?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2016

I'm looking for a shortcut to insert a math equation for Powerpoint 2016 Mac version.

I had been using PowerPoint 2010 windows, which I could "insert a math equation" using the customized ribbon. For example, I could insert a math equation by "Alt+4" if I set "insert equation" function as 4th element in the customized buttons. Please see attached pictures. This is super convenient!

[image: Customized ribbon1 (image)]

[image: Customized ribbon2 (image)]

It seems that this customized ribbon function is not implemented in Powerpoint 2016 Mac so that I cannot create a shortcut in the same manner.

Comment: try this https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225042/how-to-add-shortcut-for-insert-equation-in-powerpoint-2016 does it work for you?

Answer (score 2):

I use <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and it worked :) Good luck!

Comment: It performs an undo on my MAC :(

Comment: this doesn't work

Comment: try this https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225042/how-to-add-shortcut-for-insert-equation-in-powerpoint-2016